# Как с помощью консоли можно скомпилировать программу Си через компилятор VS2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Как с помощью консоли можно скомпилировать программу на языке C компилятором VS2010? Без использования самой студии.

Answer (score 2):

- установить Windows SDK.
- запустить Windows SDK.
- команда msbuild, указав при этом путь к solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, надо понимать, что Visual C++ 2010 у вас таки установлен, иначе вопрос смысла не имеет... Если я правильно его понимаю - вы хотите компилировать, не используя громоздкую IDE.

При установке у вас появляется такой ярлычок, как "Командная строка Visual Studio (2010)". Он открывает консольное окно, в котором вы просто вызываете компилятор (ну, или то, что вам нужно - например, `nmake` при наличии `makefile`). Какие именно ключи задавать - зависит от того, что вы хотите. Помощь - `cl /?`

Для начала простейшего

```
cl prog.c
```

вполне достаточно, чтобы скомпилировать простейшую программку. Далее смотрите, что вам нужно - оптимизация там, или статическая/динамическая линковка библиотек и т.д.

Хочется верить, что я верно понял ваш вопрос :)